# Taking screenshot of a fragment layout in Android API 31

Tags: android, screenshot

Prior to API 31 it was so easy to take screenshot of a fragment layout in Android. I just used the following code for it.

```
val mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(binding.root.width, binding.root.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
binding.root.draw(Canvas(mBitmap))
```

With the above code all the views inside the layout were drawn to the canvas. The problem is that since **API 31**, it seems just direct child views of the layout are drawn and indirect children (views inside some child `Viewgroups` of the layout) are not drawn. Should I now draw all views one by one or there is some simpler method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem with API 31. The layout which I wanted to take its screenshot  was as follows

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/poet_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/poet_coordinate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/alaki"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2000dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/shelf_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/shelf_layout"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/poet_book_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:theme="@style/DefaultRecyclerViewStyle"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/book_item"/>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/widgets"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/molding"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:tintMode="src_atop"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/molding2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/molding_bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:tintMode="src_atop"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/molding_bottom"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                app:toolbarTitle="@{item.text}"
                app:titleTextColor="?attr/colorOnSurface"
                app:menu="@menu/poet_frag_menu"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:translationZ="-1dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/wall1"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

As you can see there is a `ImageView` at the bottom of the layout with `id="@+id/wall"` which fills the entire layout. I set `translationZ="-1dp"` to send it to the background of my layout. Before API 31 everything was ok and all views were drawn to canvas. But it seems API 31 cannot realize this view is behind other views and draws it above all other views. What I did to solve this problem was to bring this `ImageView` to the top of my layout. Corrected layout became like this,

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/poet_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:translationZ="-1dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/wall1"/>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/poet_coordinate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/alaki"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2000dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/shelf_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/shelf_layout"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/poet_book_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:theme="@style/DefaultRecyclerViewStyle"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/book_item"/>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/widgets"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/molding"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:tintMode="src_atop"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/molding2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/molding_bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:tintMode="src_atop"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/molding_bottom"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                app:toolbarTitle="@{item.text}"
                app:titleTextColor="?attr/colorOnSurface"
                app:menu="@menu/poet_frag_menu"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        

    </FrameLayout>
```